# Best way to store contacts in Phone

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

It is basically an **Interview question** .

What is the best Data-Structure to be employed to store phone-numbers/Contact names in a phone directory . We should be able to retrieve number from name and vice-versa.

Few solutions i've heard of :

```
1. Create 2 Hashmaps , one maps number to name,other name to number. 
2. Create 2 Tries . Uses lesser memory than above.
```

What better can be done for it , Talking mainly about Space complexity .

Comment: How about a database, with indices on the most commonly referenced means to get a person's number (name, actual number)?

Comment: @Makoto:Is it possible for a phone ?

Comment: @Spandan: If all you're interested in is space complexity, then you can't do much better than a trie.

Comment: I think you're missing the forest for the trees, actually.  First, yes - most phones nowadays make use of SQLite.  Second, even if you weren't on a phone, using a database makes the most sense; keeping track of a person's contact information in flat files is inefficient to scan, parse, and consume.

Comment: @Makoto:Can you please post a answer of your Database method .

Comment: Just trying to understand how a trie should be used here to store phone numbers. If one defines trie as                                typedef struct trie
{
        int words;
        int prefixes;
        struct trie *edges[26];
}trie;

Answer (score 0):

I think using 2 tries is the best option, space comlexity wise. Because once you have a hash table, you'll have to handle collisions.